# How do I make an attendance sheet in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Meeting model, view, and controller. Every Meeting, I would like to take attendance of the Members of the club. Each Meeting is also associated with a Tournament.

It seems ideal to me, that each Meeting Entry would store the Tournament_id and attendence for each Member_id. However, if you were to do this, you would need a dynamic column length for the member_ids (one column for each member), which can vary.

1. Is that possible?
2. If that is not the best way, what is the best way to store the data?

Currently, I have it where each Meeting.id stores 1 Member's Attendance and the form rolls out all Members for 1 given tournament and a check box for their attendance. However, I don't fully understand how that is working, and I can't figure out how to easily Edit the member's attendance that way.

I got part of the solution of my current functionality from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71686405/submitting-multiple-table-entries-from-a-single-form-submission-in-rails), but was trying to find out if there is another way to get it fully working.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems ideal to me, that each Meeting Entry would store the
> Tournament_id and attendence for each Member_id. However, if you were
> to do this, you would need a dynamic column length for the member_ids
> (one column for each member), which can vary.

**Big nope.** That's not a tenable solution for modeling data in a relational database as the schema would be completely unmaintable and you would end up with a huge amount of columns that almost entirely contain nulls. The SQL queries would also be very crazy.

You instead need to think in terms of each row in a table containing the unique data for each member. In database design this corresponds to the concept [First Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).

This is a simplefied example of how you would keep track of attendence*:

```erb
class Member
  has_many :attendences
  has_many :meetings, through: :attendences
end

class Meeting
  has_many :attendences
  has_many :members, through: :attendences
end

# rails g model attendence member:belongs_to meeting:belong
class Attendence < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :member
  belongs_to :meeting
end
```

Here `attendences` is a join table containing the member and meeting ids and we have a many to many assocation between Member and Meeting.

You can then just use the rails form helpers for creating checkboxes from collections together with the `member_ids` setter / getter created by `has_many :members, through: :attendences`:

```
<%= form_with(model: @meeting) do |form| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :member_ids, 'Members in attendence' %>
    <%= form.collection_checkboxes :member_ids, @available_members, :id, :name %>
  </div>

  # ...
<% end %>
```

In your controller you would then whitelist the `member_ids` column with a hash key with an empty array as the value:

```
class MeetingsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @meeting = Meeting.new
    @available_members = Member.all
  end 

  def create
    @meeting = Meeting.new(meeting_params)
    if @meeting.save
      redirect_to @meeting
    else
      @available_members = Member.all
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def meeting_params
    params.require(:meeting)
          .permit(:foo, :bar, :baz, member_ids: [])
  end
end
```

This will permit an array of permitted scalar values such as a list of ids.

Comment: I'm very aware that this doesn't match your exact buisness requirements - but you really need to understand the basic concepts here and I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: Also if you where building something like the list that a student uses to check off the pupils at the start of a class you would instead create the list of the expected members first and then use nested attributes to record if each expected member is actually present or not. This may be way beyond your current skill level though.

Comment: Yes, basically now im rolling out a list of Active Members, and checking if they are present or not, but i dont full understand whats going on in the controller and form, which i had got from the link i posted. Thanks for the thorough answer, its going to help me a lot!